# Problems with custom post type and hierarchical permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, taxonomy

I have a custom post type "films" and a hierarchical taxonomy "genre" (terror,drama, action)
I would like to obtain this urls:

```
www.domain.com/films  ----------------------------------> all the films
www.domain.com/films/terror/ ---------------------------> all terror films
www.domain.com/films/terror/vampires -------------------> all vampire films
www.domain.com/films/terror/vampires/post-name ---------> the post
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Any ideas, please?

Comment: [This](http://hardcorewp.com/2014/hardcore-url-routing-for-wordpress/) might help.